# Escape backslash

Tags: string, escape

I'm trying to define a string with the following value

```
string s = 'Something\Something';
```

but I got  Illegal character sequence '\S' in string literal.

I tried escaping the backlash with another backlash but I ended up with a string that has two backlashes ('Something\\Something') . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\\` instead `\`

```
string s = 'Something\\Something';

system.debug(s);
```

Output

> 19:13:22:003 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|Something\Something